# Angular 5 white screen of death

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

### My Angular app suddenly showed a white screen of death...

I'm starting the app using `ng serve` from `@angular/cli`.

---

The sources are loaded but the `main.ts` file is never reached and there is no error in the console.

[image]
[image]

Webpack does not stop saying that there are no changed blocks, even if I modify some files.

[image]

#### I tried:

- Refresh the browser
- Open the app in another browser
- Restart the webpack server.
- Go back to an older working commit
- Build the app using `ng build --prod` and run the output using an HTTP server
- Reinstall `@angular/cli`

#### Application:

[image]
[image]

#### Environment:

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: No, the console is empty and I have no error from @angular/cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by inspecting each last commit one by one until I found the broken one. The problem was in the `tsconfig.json` file so I canceled that commit. I still do not know why this config (`tsconfig.json`) breaks the build and why there was no error message.

Here is the rollback commit: 
[image]

Comment: isn't `noEmit: true` telling the Typescript compiler to not emit Javascript? That would explain why your `main.ts` was never executed - because it was not emitted by Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have the rep to just add a comment so I posted an alternative answer).

I had the white screen of death no errors for angular 7.0.0-rc1 after about an hour I found that in my code I had incorrectly formatted an *ngFor

I had: *ngFor="let client **in** quote.clients"

instead of: *ngFor="let client **of** quote.clients"

This use to give a nice message on build or within the console but for some reason it's currently white screening with no errors and building fine.

Hope this saves someone some time.